# Disable a submit button when one of the fields is empty

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to disable a submit button when **one or more** of the selectors (generated dynamically) shown in the picture are empty..

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4nng.png]

I tried the following jQuery code:

```
    <script>

    var $submit = $("input[name=store_values]");
    $(".ownlevelselect").each(function(){
    if($(".ownlevelselect:empty").length>0){
        $submit.attr("disabled","disabled");
    }else {
        $submit.removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    });

</script>
```

and these are the relevant parts of my form:

```
   echo "<select class='ownlevelselect' id='ownlevelselect' name='level-".$compi['Competence_ID']."' >";
```

and the input buttons:

```
   echo "<input type='submit' name='submit_values' value='Save'>";
  echo "<input type='submit' name='store_values' value='Store'></form>";
```

The one I want to disable is the one with `name='store_values'`

Comment: Wrong approach. You need to handle the `.change()` event of your "selectors" and do your logic in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something ambiguous in your question, do you mean empty like DOM empty (selects that contains no elements) or empty like selects with an empty value selected ?

If you mean empty like **emtpy value**, you can try this, handling change event like Shadow Wizard said:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    var submitButton = $('input[name="store_values"]');
    /* Called to disable button on page load, done here but probably possible server-side */
    checkValues()

    /* Called on change event on dropdowns */       
    $('select.ownlevelselect').on('change',function(){
        checkValues();
    });

    function checkValues(){
        /* Disable button if found an empty <select> (mean, no <option> inside), or a select with an empty value selected */
        submitButton.prop('disabled',$(".ownlevelselect > option:selected[value=''],.ownlevelselect:empty").length > 0);
    }
});
```

If you mean empty like "Dom empty" (no option defined inside the select), you can try this (you can place it into a function and call it each time you dynamically add an element)

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var submitButton = $('input[name="store_values"]');
    submitButton.prop('disabled',$(".ownlevelselect:empty").length > 0);
});
```

**EDIT**

Be carefull about your IDs, I don't have any relevant part of code to be sure, but you seem to reuse same ID for your selects, which is a bad idea :)

**EDIT2**

Here's a fiddle, so as you can see if I missed something:
http://jsfiddle.net/d8rb9/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I meant DOM empty: when nothing is selected. I tried your code, but nothing happened. I think we are missing an `.each`function here because I have several selects in the form..

Comment: Thank you Sir. I have uploaded an edited fiddle in which the selects appear similar to mine. You can see that the post button is always enabled.. I have no idea why really.
http://jsfiddle.net/d8rb9/3/

Comment: I used the first method with the non-DOM. and it worked.
Thanks a lot ! (upvoted and accepted)

Comment: Thx :) in your last fiddle it doesn't worked because all your select contained <option> elements, and the :empty selector check the presence of elements inside the selected one, it doesn't check for the values. I updated your fiddle, just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/d8rb9/5/

Answer (score -1):

you can use the event onBlur for each select to trigger a function that tests if all the other select are not empty, and then activate the submit button if so.

here is an exemple:

**The select Tag :**

```
<select class="ownLevelSelect" onBlur="checkSelects()">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

**The Javascript function:**

```
<script>
    function checkSelects(){

        // integer to count the number of select with a correct value
        var nonEmpty = 0;

        // loop on all the select in the page with the class attribute : "ownLevelSelect"
        $('.ownLevelSelect').each(function(){
            if($(this).val()) {
                nonEmpty++;
            }
        });

        //desactivate the submit button if the number of selects in the page <> nonEmpty
        ($('.ownLevelSelect').length == nonEmpty)? $('#theSubmit').removeAttr("disabled") : $('#theSubmit').attr("disabled","disabled");
                }
</script>
```

and maybe you need to call this function on page load so the button is disabled by default if one of the fields are empty

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        checkSelects();
    });
</script>
```

Note : 
    The ID attribut must be unique on the page, so in your code change this :

```
<select class='ownlevelselect' id='ownlevelselect' name='level-".$compi['Competence_ID']."' >";

By this : 

<select class='ownlevelselect' id='ownlevelselect-".$compi['Competence_ID']."' name='level-".$compi['Competence_ID']."' >";
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: using inline js events should not be encourage in my opinion. .blur() is available in jquery and can easily be applied.